# How to resolve android studio installation error("Your android studio installation is corrupt and will not work properly.")?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I had my Android studio 2.2 prev 2 initially and then it asked for an update. I downloaded it and i found the files that were there in the download was similar to the folder Android\Android Studio in my C: drive. So I backed up the older files in the Android folder and moved the downloaded ones. Then when I opened android studio, it said "Your android studio installation is corrupt and will not work properly."

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this one. This error is shown when the older files of your previous version of Android studio(2.2 prev2 in this case) are still there in that folder Do this.,..
Go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
**Delete all those stuff** you have there.(No worries, relax and do that)
Copy the downloaded files.
**Paste in the same location** (C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio)
Run Android studio. It works!!

P.S I was the one who asked this question and later my dumb brain got this idea.
Hope it helps others..